# Asp.net identity authentication - replace homepage with log in page & only logged in user can access

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

how to implement Asp.net identity authentication - replace homepage with log in page & only logged in user can access?
So if i new a mvc project. it has a homepage with home, about, contact & register link on top right. But i want a log in page to be the first page and only logged in user can access to the homepage mentioned above. and will have it done with asp.net identity. How to start? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the default route such that it goes to login controller instead of Home controller. Please see the sample code belowl

```
 routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Login", action = "Your Action", id = UrlParameter.Optional},

);
```